# How to skip motherboard boot manager when powering on?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd, multi-boot, grub

I have an asrock z170 pro4s and I just bought an samsung 960 evo. I reinstalled windows 10 on the ssd in uefi mode, then I created a partition on the ssd and installed ubuntu 16.04. Now when I boot my pc I get the motherboards boot manager screen asking me to select either boot device 1 or boot device 2. If I choose boot device 1 I boot into windows, if I choose boot device 2 I get the ubuntu grub menu where again I can choose to boot into ubuntu or windows.

My question is how can I skip the boot manager part when booting my pc and boot straight into the grub menu since from the grub menu I can boot into ubuntu or windows with one click?

When I go into my bios I have three boot options 1. ubuntu (samsung 960 evo) 2. ubuntu (samsung 960 evo) again 3. windows boot manager.

I don't know why it says ubuntu twice when one of them should be the windows 10 partition.
It seems like whatever order I put these in it always boots the asrock boot manager?

Comment: It's weird that the UEFI boot menu would *always* pop up. Does it happen before you got Ubuntu installed? I wonder if it's because you created an extra EFI system partition in addition to the one created during Windows installation.

Comment: @Tom Yan yea it also happened before I installed ubuntu and that time it would only show me boot device 1 because I only had windows installed. When I installed windows I let it create all of the partitions on its own, I can check what it created and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it in `Tool` -> `Boot Manager` in your UEFI setting (`F2` / `DEL`)

[image]

Ref.: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z170%20Pro4S/index.us.asp?cat=Manual (User Manual)